# Blackberry HTTP Request too slow

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me

I am making an HTTP request in an app, and it doesn't matter if I make it through WiFi, TCP or WAP2; it always takes between 8 and 15 seconds. Has this ever happened to anybody else? Any advices on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if you request for example 1G file I wouldn't be suprised if it takes even longer ...

Comment: Is this on an actual device or in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

No, this hasn't happened to me.

What about trying:

- to connect to different URLs
- to use a socket connection

Answer (score 0):

If you use simulators I can't really help you because I use them very rarely since they are quite unreliable for many things.Here are a few things you can check in case you are using a device:

1)Try different urls, maybe even try making connection to your device. I am not sure if locator string allows localhost so you might need to use your device ip address

2)As mentioned before try even a socket connection or even a DatagramConnection to see if any connection can be made quickly.

3)Make sure your device isn't overloaded with apps running which do some heavy networking.

4)Check again your code to see if really the connection creation is taking so much time. Try measuring time with System.currentTimeMillis() right before and after the Connector#open() call. Make sure you don't create connections too often - in a loop for example.

5)Make all these tests while not in debug mode because in my experience when the device has attached debugger it does some strange things from time to time. Just run apps normally.